# A delay in time when reading a large file (Stopwatch batch file)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

So, my file is a stopwatch file. It has to read 1000 lines of code and come back to the same page in a second.

```
choice /c 12c /n /t 1 /d c
```

The code above lets you have 1 second to respond (choose 1 or 2). So, the problem with that is that when it needs to read 1000 lines of code it takes it more than 1ms. So it has a huge delay when its 1 second in addition to the time to read 1000+ lines of code.

So, is there a way to have a constant 1 second choice command. Or can I have it so it lets you respond with 0 second delay but it has the code in it

```
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 1000 >NUL
```

The command above works great but it doesn't allow for user input. So if I could in cooperate the above command with this one

```
choice /c 12c /n /t 1 /d c
```

Thank you.

Comment: 1ms is not a "huge delay" when compared to an interval 1000 times as long.  What are you doing that takes user input but still needs timing so precise that 1000ms is okay and 1001ms is too long?  Note that the `ping` command you entered is WAY more inaccurate than that.

Comment: The problem is is that im making a stopwatch with how many laps you want. For example if the user wants to have 100 laps the time should be at 60, instead it is at 53. 7 seconds for a stopwatch every 60 seconds with 100 laps is pretty significant. Also, i accidently wrote the delay is only 1ms. The code is here: http://www.mediafire.com/download/fj2zv123nt1ib8c/Stopwatch.rar Just follow the setup and it should be pretty easy. Not everything works 100% yet.

Comment: Expecting less than 1 second accuracy when measuring times in a batch file is unrealistic. Consider switching to a different programming language.